# How should classification be done for a very small data set?

Tags: classification, dataset

I am looking at data from the London Data Store based on social characteristics between London boroughs.

Since there are only about 30 London boroughs, the data sets I am looking at are naturally very small. For example, I might be fitting regression/correlations to a plot of about 30 points.

1. What are appropriate ways to conduct classification on such small data sets, and why? 'Why' is important.

I was thinking of something like SVM, or Naive Bayes. Or regression if the data is continuous.

2. What are very inappropriate ways to conduct classification here?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to predict? Which borough it is given a certain set of characteristics? This might be helpful: https://medium.com/rants-on-machine-learning/what-to-do-with-small-data-d253254d1a89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need some classification algorithm, you can use your basic understanding on data/ Business Knowledge to do the classification. As the number of data points are too low, the model cannot give you good/generalised results.

Even if you try applying some complex algorithm like **SVM/NN**, it is of no use as the data is too low.

If you still want to apply some machine learning algorithm and then you can apply **Naive Bayes, Decision Tree** as these are the basic algorithms, can do the job.